# Traverse a table using jQuery, XML, JSON, JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, json

Sorry for the misleading title but I'm unsure how else to write it.

I have the below table...

[image]

I want to produce a simple calculator that compares all data in a row from 2 given parameters.

I will ask my users to select a country first, and then select a value in that column. After doing this you can submit the form and it would output the correct values from that given row...

I've made a fiddle to try and show what I mean...

http://jsfiddle.net/SLCaN/2/

What is the best way to do this? The only way I am aware of is by having a huge if/else statement which will take me forever to write.

```
$('.country').on('change', function(){
// If USA show corrent dropdown
if( $(this).val() == 'usa'){
    $('.hiddenGrade').hide();
    $('.iniValusa').show();
} else if( $(this).val() == 'gb'){
    $('.hiddenGrade').hide();
    $('.iniValgb').show();
} else {
    $('.hiddenGrade').hide();
    $('.iniValfr').show();
}
});

$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('p').text('Values output here');
});
```

---

If you select `French` and `5a+` you would get `5.8 and V-Diff` in the output...

Comment: Have you considered using a JavaScript object as a map? The value of the country selection would be the property name, and then the value of the property could be the the selector used to show the div. Alternatively, you could just concatenate the value of country selection to the class name for your jQuery selector.

Comment: Are you also trying to dynamically generate the `<select>` options from the table contents in JavaScript, or has your backend code already handled that?

Comment: That's already sorted @MichaelBerkowski, it's just the comparison I can't quite figure out

Comment: It is not quite clear what you want to do here. Also, I'm not sure how you expect to get `5.8 and V-Diff` as the output when you select `French` and `5A+`? Shouldn't the output be `'' and V-Diff`?

Comment: @Liam You really should clarify what you need here. Please post exact samples of what input would be and what _exact_ output is expected, since per the other comments, it really isn't obvious what you need. We could have solved it three days ago without you having to spend 500rep on a bounty.

Comment: Do the values originate in an HTML table? A JSON object?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the mapping is many to one? If you select US 5.7, for UK you get both Diff and V-Diff? What would you like to happen then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely different ways to do this, but it seems to me that it comes down to the data structure. My personal take is to go with a data structure that has an array of countries with grades. The grades would then actually be pairs (display value/actual value) to account for the gaps in the data. The trick here is that we don't want to display empty display values in the select, but we do need data (in actual value) for conversion. After that, the jQuery stuff is pretty easy.

Data like this:

```
var countryGrades = [
    { country : "France", grades : [ 
        ["4", "4"], 
        ["", "4"], 
        ["5a", "5a"], 
        ["5a+", "5a+"], 
        ["5b", "5b"],
        ["5b+", "5b+"], 
        ["5c", "5c"],
        ["5c+", "5c+"],
        ["6a", "6a"],
        ["6a+", "6a+"],
        ["6b", "6b"] 
    ]},
    { country : "USA", grades : [ 
        ["5.6", "5.6"], 
        ["", "5.6"], 
        ["5.7", "5.7"], 
        ["", "5.7"], 
        ["5.8", "5.8"], 
        ["", "5.8"], 
        ["5.9", "5.9"], 
        ["5.10a", "5.10a"], 
        ["5.10b", "5.10b"], 
        ["5.10c", "5.10c"], 
        ["5.10d", "5.10d"]
    ]},
    { country : "UK", grades : [ 
        ["", ""], 
        ["Mod", "Mod"], 
        ["Diff", "Diff"], 
        ["V-Diff", "V-Diff"], 
        ["4a", "4a"], 
        ["4b", "4b"], 
        ["4b VS", "4b VS"], 
        ["4c HVS", "4c HVS"], 
        ["5a E1", "5a E1"], 
        ["", ""], 
        ["", ""]
    ]}
];
```

Event handling, etc. like this:

```
function loadGrades(countryGradesIndex) {
    var gradeSelect = $("#grade");
    gradeSelect.empty();        
    $.each(countryGrades[countryGradesIndex].grades, function(index, grade) {
        if (grade[0] != "") {
            gradeSelect.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", index).text(grade[0]));
        }           
    });
}

$.each(countryGrades, function(index, countryGrade) {       
    $("#country").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", index).text(countryGrade.country));
});

$("#country").on("change", function() {
    loadGrades($("#country").val());
});

loadGrades(0);

$("#convert").on("click", function() {
    var gradeIndex = $("#grade").val();
    var gradeConversion = "";
    $.each(countryGrades, function(countryGradesIndex) {
        gradeConversion += countryGrades[countryGradesIndex].country + ": " + countryGrades[countryGradesIndex].grades[gradeIndex][1] + "<br>";
    });

    $("#conversions").html(gradeConversion);
});
```

Check out a working JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tetonraven/SVj63/

Answer (score 1):

crush's solution seems to me the most practical. You define the data in a single variable, then use it to populate both SELECTs. However, consider that Michael's solution can be adapted to degrade better: my take on crush's solution, if Javascript were disabled, would get you an empty page.

You keep all the data in a Javascript object, and the values are indexed so that equal grades have equal indexes (the row numbers in your table):

```
 4: "quatrième valeur pour les français",
 ...
 4: "Fourth value for UK",
```

This approach allows to "translate" more easily (I believe) one array into the other, i.e. you select France, get grade 5b, change France to US: the *value* stays the same, which means that the displayed grade changes to the corresponding value in the new country.

Also, you keep all your data in a single place.

For large country arrays, I'd suggest to convert the `grades[countryCode]` into an AJAX call to fetch that particular country from the server. You'd also need another AJAX call to only fetch the *codes* from the server.

```
  var grades = {
    fr: {
        name: 'France',
        values: {
            0: "4",
            1: "4",
            2: "5a",
            3: "5a+",
            4: "5b",
            5: "5b+",
            6: "5c",
            7: "5c+",
            8: "6a",
            9: "6a+",
           10: "6b"
        }
     },
 us:    {
        name: 'USA',
        values: {
            0: "5.6",
            1: "5.6",
            2: "5.7",
            3: "5.7",
            4: "5.8",
            5: "5.8",
            6: "5.9",
            7: "5.10a",
            8: "5.10b",
            9: "5.10c",
           10: "5.10d"
        }
    },
'gb': {
        name: 'UK',
        values: {
            0: "",
            1: "Mod",
            2: "Diff",
            3: "V-Diff",
            4: "4a",
            5: "4b",
            6: "4b VS",
            7: "4c HVS",
            8: "5a E1",
            9: "",
           10: ""
        }
  }
}


  function setSelectTo(country) {
      // TODO: verify that country is indeed in grades
      var data = grades[country].values;
      var $el = $("#gradeSelect");
      $cur = $el.val();
      $el.empty();
      $.each(data, function(value, text) {
          $el
             .append($("<option></option>")
             .attr("value", value)
             .text(text));
      });
      // Restore value
      $el.val($cur);
  }
  function populateCountrySelect() {
      var $el = $("#countrySelect");
      $el.empty();

      $.each(grades, function(code, data) {
          $el
             .append($("<option></option>")
             .attr("value", code)
             .text(data.name));
      });
  }

  $('#countrySelect').on('change', function(){
      setSelectTo($(this).val());
  });

  populateCountrySelect();
  $('#countrySelect').val('us');
  setSelectTo('us');
  $('#gradeSelect').val(2);
```

This is an updated [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7wWJ/1/) - sorry, the first URL was wrong - and the HTML is very minimal:

```
Choose your country: <select id="countrySelect"></select>
<br />
Choose your grade: <select id="gradeSelect"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Iserni's Answer is really close to what you need, I think they missed the output portion though unless I'm reading/understanding the code incorrectly.

To adapt that answer a bit I would change the data structure to be:

```
var grades = [
{'fr': "4", 'usa': "5.6",'gb': ""},
{'fr': "4", 'usa': "5.6",'gb': "Mod"},
{'fr': "5a",    'usa': "5.7",'gb': "Diff"},
{'fr': "5a+",   'usa': "5.7",'gb': "V-Diff"},
{'fr': "5b",    'usa': "5.8",'gb': "4a"},
{'fr': "5b+",   'usa': "5.8",'gb': "4b"},
{'fr': "5c",    'usa': "5.9",'gb': "4b VS"},
{'fr': "5c+",   'usa': "5.10a",'gb': "4c HVS"},
{'fr': "6a",    'usa': "5.10b",'gb': "5a E1"},
{'fr': "6a+",   'usa': "5.10c",'gb': ""},
{'fr': "6b",    'usa': "5.10d",'gb': ""}];
```

Then in your click event something like this will get you to translated values (you will need to adapt it a bit)

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var matches = $.grep(grades,function(e) {
     return e[$(".country").val()] == $('.iniValusa').val()
   });

   if(matches.length == 1)
   {
     $('p').text('USA: ' + matches[0].usa + ' GB: ' + matches[0].gb + 'FR: ' + matches[0].fr);
   } 
});
```

Comment: Yes, maybe the "translation" part is a bit obscure. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding adding my 2 penny to access the data, and hope its helpful.

Keep data like every first select value and the grade value array .

```
 var data = { 
 fr :new Array("4","4","5a","5a+", "5b","5b+","5c","5c+","6a","6a+", "6b"),  

 usa : new Array(  "5.6","5.6","5.7", "5.7","5.8", "5.8", "5.9", "5.10a", "5.10b","5.10c", "5.10d"), 

 gb : new Array (  "", "Mod","Diff","V-Diff", "4a","4b", "4b VS", "4c HVS", "5a E1", "","")                            

};
```

Then write the method to populate that grades when country clicks.

```
function populate(val)
{    
      $("#grade").empty();   
    var array = data[val];   
   for(var a=0; a<array.length; a++ ) {
     $("#grade").append('<option value="'+ a +  '">' +  array[a] + '</option>');
}    
 }    
}
```

And call the methods something like that ::

```
$("document").ready(function () { populate('usa'); } );
$('.country').on('change', function(){
    populate($(this).val());  
});
```

Html will be simple (only country u need to per-populate [U can write the method to poulate them in document ready also]. This the output way to print all content to select index :  {As per ur expected o/p my understanding is u skiping the empty value, u can add that cond here if that the case something like this : if(data[a][index] == '') data[a][index+1] (though u have to take care array len etc.) }

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = $('#grade').find(":selected").val();
     var str = "";
     for(var a in data)
     {         
        str  = str +" " + $('.country option[value="' + a + '"]').html() 
        +" " + data[a][index];
    }
    $('p').text('Values output here ' + str);
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SLCaN/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't exactly know how you want. But I tried that with `html table + jQuery` and here is what you can get.

#### DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/xEzLv/

You only need 3 if statements and see the result.

```
$('.country').on('change', function(){
    $('.hiddenGrade').hide();
    $('#s_'+$(this).val()).show();
    $('#cn').val($(this).val());
    $('#result').val('');
});
$('.hiddenGrade').on('change', function(){
    $('#cn_val').val($(this).val());
    $('#chart tr').css('background', 'none');
    $('#chart tr').eq($(this).val()).css('background', 'green');
});

$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#cn').val() === '0'){
        $('#result').val(
            $('#chart tr').eq($('#cn_val').val()).find('td').eq(1).text()+', '+
            $('#chart tr').eq($('#cn_val').val()).find('td').eq(2).text()   
        );
    }
    if($('#cn').val() === '1'){
        $('#result').val(
            $('#chart tr').eq($('#cn_val').val()).find('td').eq(0).text()+', '+
            $('#chart tr').eq($('#cn_val').val()).find('td').eq(2).text()   
        );
    }
    if($('#cn').val() === '2'){
        $('#result').val(
            $('#chart tr').eq($('#cn_val').val()).find('td').eq(0).text()+', '+
            $('#chart tr').eq($('#cn_val').val()).find('td').eq(1).text()   
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Check my answer, you could have get read of all your if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like enormous ammount of code other answers have. Check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/kP249/1/.

```
Just put data in table:

<select id='country'>
    <option value="0">Fr</option>
    <option value="1">Us</option>
    <option value="2">Uk</option>
</select>
<input id='score' type="text" />    

<table id="results">
    <thead><tr><td>Fr</td><td>Us</td><td>Uk</td></tr></thead><tbody>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>5.6</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>5.6</td><td>Mod</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5a</td><td>5.7</td><td>Diff</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5a+</td><td>5.7</td><td>V-Diff</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5b</td><td>5.8</td><td>4a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5b+</td><td>5.8</td><td>4b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5c</td><td>5.9</td><td>4b VS</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5c+</td><td>5.10a</td><td>4c HVS</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6a</td><td>5.10b</td><td>5a E1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6a+</td><td>5.10c</td><td></td></tr>                   
</tbody></table>
```

And add little bit of javascript:

```
var $score = $('#score'), $country = $('#country')
  , $results = $('#results'), $rows = $results.find('tbody tr')

$rows.hide()

$results.on('scoreChanged', function(e, country, score) {
    $rows.hide().filter(function(i) {
        return $(this).find('td:eq(' + country + ')').text() == score
    }).show()
})

$score.on('submit, blur', function(e) {
  $results.trigger('scoreChanged', [$country.val(), $score.val()])  
})

$country.on('changed', function(e) {
  $results.trigger('scoreChanged', [$country.val(), $score.val()])  
})
```

**NOTE:** you can slightly change filter condition and show results more friendly ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/kP249/3/)):

```
$results.on('scoreChanged', function(e, country, score) {
    $rows.hide().filter(function(i) {
        return $(this).find('td:eq(' + country + ')').text().contains(score)
    }).show()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            var values = [['', '', ''], ['4', '5.6', 'x'], ['5a', '5.7', 'dif']];
            var countries = ['-', 'fr', 'us', 'uk'];
            var jq_country =  $('.country'), jq_grade = $('.grade');

            $.each(countries, function(index, val){
               jq_country.append('<option data-index="' + index + '">' + val + '</option>');                
            });

            var curr_col, curr_index;

            jq_country.change(function() {
                jq_grade.empty();     
                $('.result').val('');

                curr_col = parseInt($(this).find('option:selected').data('index')) - 1;     

                if (curr_col >= 0) {

                    $.each(values, function(index, val) {

                        jq_grade.append('<option ' + (index == curr_index ? 'selected' : '' ) +  ' value="' + index + '">' + val[curr_col] + '</option>')   
                    });


                    jq_grade.change();
                }

            });

            jq_grade.change(function() {
                curr_index = parseInt(jq_grade.val());
                if (curr_index) {
                    var result = '';
                    $.each(countries.slice(1), function(index, val){
                        if (index != curr_col) result += val + ':' + values[curr_index][index] + ';';
                    });

                    $('.result').val(result);
                }
                else {
                    $('.result').val('');
                }
            });            

        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
       <select class="country"></select>
      <select class="grade"></select>
      <input type="text" class="result" />
   </form>

</body>
</html>
```